# Is there possible to convert a base64 code to a file like it has been got from input type file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file, input, base64

I would like to know if there's a way to convert a b64 string to a file like it has been get from a `<input type="file"/>`.

I've got this function to do something like this:

```
function filefy(url, filename, mime_type) {
    return fetch(url)
            .then(res => res.arrayBuffer())
            .then(buf => new File([buf], filename, {type: mime_type}));
}
```

It returns a File Object like this:

[image]

To do it, i've used the filefy function this way:

```
filefy("data:image/jpeg;base64," + image, 
    new Date().getTime()+'.jpg', 
    'image/jpeg'
).then(file => {
    console.log(file);
    console.log(new FileReader().readAsBinaryString(file));

    var fd = new FormData();

    fd.append('file[]', file);
    fd.append('type', 'galeria');
    fd.append('timestamp', vm.timestamp);
    fd.append('user_id', 2);

    console.warn(fd.get('file[]'));

    $http.post(my_api_url + 'uploadedthings', fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    }).success(response => {
        console.log('ok', response);
    }).error(error => {
        console.log('erro', error);
    });
});
```

My Laravel API does'nt recognize this file format. When I use from my web client (This code has been used in a Cordova App), in a `<input type="file"/>` it works.

I have printed the file format from this Input, and it looks like:

[image]

Comment: This logs/warns is just testing. I've forgot to remove then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of your `filefy` function to create a virtual File object, you could simply use a Blob:

```
var blob = new Blob([image], { type: "image/jpeg"});
fd.append('file[]', blob, new Date().getTime()+'.jpg');
```

You might need to convert the base64 string representation of the image to a byte array (or use `canvas.toBlob`).

More infos:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob